# Are spring .jar files afected by upcoming Oracle restriction treating MD5 signed jar files as unsigned?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jar

Our team is using STS version 3.64 and 3.8x.  Per Oracle,
"Starting with the April Critical Patch Update releases, planned for April 18 2017, all JRE versions will treat JARs signed with MD5 as unsigned. "

Since the JRE is required to run Spring Tool Suite, will any .jar files from this earlier version be affected?  We are planning to upgrade to the latest version of Spring in the near future, but that will take some time.

Anyone know?

Comment: I don't think STS checks jar signatures. That was (as far as I know) only used by applets. And they're dead.

Comment: Thanks.  If it is only applets, we're good.  I thought the JRE might check the STS jar files as it loads them since the JRE will be the 'watch dog.'